# Make custom iso debian file

Tags: debian, iso, preseed

I tried to create a custom distribution based on debian, after reading debian document, I found preseed file that can generate debian with preconfigured parameters. But this is not enough for me, because I need to add some packages with their dependencies in the generated iso file, and I need to script execution after installation of my custom debian, this script can compile and install my software with a shell script.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are scripts here: https://github.com/dotzero/vagrant-debian-wheezy-64 to take a netinst iso and remaster it with preseed options.  This could be a good starting point.

There is a latecmd option in the preseed that will let you run a command just before the installation finishes.  If the latecmd can't do everything in the chroot environment, you can use the latecmd to insert a script that will be called at the next boot.

Answer (score 1):

I would like suggest to use the [Live System](http://live.debian.net/) project (in Debian the according deb-package is called `live-build`). I have used it to create custom Debian-based [live images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) and installers. This tool allows to manage a lot of features: system architecture, installed packages, custom content, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be, that you create your (virtual) machine with a regular Debian-CD and use preseed to automate the installation. After that you need to connect to your machine and add your key to the debian keyring to allow you to install your own packages. Then you'll need add your repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` in order to  install everything else as you need it easily. Everything can be automated by using scripts.